# Android Studio y Git con Firebase, distinto proyecto para cada Branch

Tags: android, firebase, git

Quería hacer una consulta porque no se cómo seguir. Tengo un proyecto en Android Studio funcionando con Firebase (uso los servicios Storage, realTime Database y Auth). A su vez, manejo las versiones del proyecto con Git. Ahora estaba interesado en tener un branch que se conecte a un proyecto diferente de la misma cuenta de Firebase y con otro branch lo mismo. Mi idea es tener un proyecto de desarrollo y otro de producción.

Por lo que encontré y entendí de internet, la mejor manera de tener una base de datos para desarrollo y otra para producción en Firebase es tener dos proyectos (de ahí mi necesidad) y de Android, encontré que utilizan Git para mantener las dos versiones. A su vez, encontré que utilizan el gradle para setear algo de desarrollo y algo de producción pero no entendí que era y creo que no es lo que necesito.

Espero que se entienda mi inquietud, agradezco cualquier consejo o ayuda!

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta y no entiendo que tendría que ver `git` con esto. ¿No sería cuestión de tener en la Play Store una versión de prueba y otra en producción?

Comment: Cedano, gracias por tomarte la molestia de leer la pregunta. No estaba enterado que puedo usar dos versiones en el Play Store, lo voy a revisar. Basicamente lo que quiero es tener la misma aplicación Android pero conectada a diferentes proyectos de Firebase. Necesito esto para poder trabajar una app con la base de datos de desarrollo, mientras la otra app con su base de datos Firebase independiente ya esta en producción. Espero que se entienda mejor mi duda, y como dije voy a investigar lo mencionado sobre el Play Store. Gracias!

Comment: Sí puedes. Digamos que la versión 1.0  es tu versión actual en producción, y quieres tener una nueva versión de tu App, puedes crear una versión 1.1 y subirla a Play Store como versión beta. En el código de esa versión 1.1 apuntas a otra base de datos de Firebase y listo. Luego, si quieres subirla como definitiva, la sacas de beta y la pones como definitiva (ahí reemplazará a la versión 1)  y la pones a apuntar de nuevo a la base de datos Firebase definitiva. Aunque esto tendría sentido solamente si quieres que más usuarios prueben la App. Si es para pruebas tuyas solo, con que la instales...

Comment: ...en tu dispositivo bastaría. Por ejemplo ahora estoy preparando una nueva versión de mi App, la tengo instalada en mi dispositivo y voy haciendo las pruebas con ella (**en mi teléfono** borré la versión 1.0 instalada desde Play Store e instalé por USB la futura nueva versión desde Android Studio), mientras, todos los demás usuarios están usando y descargando la versión en producción. Cuando termine de hacer mis pruebas subiré esa nueva versión y listo.

Comment: Buenísimo! Para la semana que viene te traigo una respuesta de cómo me fue (no puedo antes, tengo que rendir ^^). Mil gracias por tu ayuda!